# altering the parsed html of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK, I have this html structure

```
<table id="list">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr><td class="container"><input class="myname" type="text" value="Roi" /></td></tr>
         <tr><td class="container"><input class="myname" type="text" value="Sam" /></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I wanted to send this table via email which will be no problem, the problem I am facing is if I send it exactly as what it is, its a bit wrong since there is an `input` element

So my plan is I will replace that `inputs` with the plain value only and I can achieve this using the following code :

```
$( ".myname" ).each(function( index ) {
    var name = this.val();
    this.closest(".container").html(name);
});
```

That would work if we are talking about the actual page but I don't want to alter the actual page so I came up with this :

```
var html = jQuery("#list").html();
html = jQuery.parseHTML(html);
```

Now, how can I do the same thing in the `html` variable?

Comment: on a sidenote: `id`s have to be unique and may only appear once in a document. so better change `id="container"` to `class="container"`

Comment: oh yes, I forgot about that sorry

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get what I wanted using the following

```
jQuery('#send').click(function() {
    var html = jQuery("#list").html();
    jQuery(html).find('.container').each( function() {
        var oldcontent = jQuery(this).html();
        var newcontent = jQuery(this).children(".myname").val();
        html = html.replace(oldcontent, newcontent);
    });
});
```

I figured I can use it as a `string` no need to `parseHTML` it and use the `replace()` function.
Thanks to Arun's answer, I can't use his answer because for the some cases that there is a multiple element inside the `<td>` and `replaceWith` will be not the best way because it just replaces a single element.

I'm still open for a better answer I feel my answer is kind of a cheat and assumes there will be no the same name.

But it will prevent the error of having the presence of the same name if the `.myname` class has their own IDs.

Comment: Even if there are multiple elements in a `td` I'm replacing only the `input` element so rest of the contents will remain the same

Answer (score -2):

Try

```js
//create a temp cloned version of the table
var $div = $('<div />').append(jQuery("#list").clone());

//alter the temp html structure
$div.find('.myname').replaceWith(function () {
    return this.value;
});

//obtain the updated html from the temp element
var html = $div.html();

$('#log').text(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="container">
        <input class="myname" type="text" value="Roi" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="container">
        <input class="myname" type="text" value="Sam" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: @Roi what is the expected output